# How to generate LLVM bitcode and disassembled code having similar variable names of source code

Tags: clang, llvm

I am trying to generate LLVM bitcode and disassembled (.ll) code from a c source code. I want the instructions in the bitcode to have similar variable names as the source code.

Suppose I have a source code (sample.c):

```
  int test(int a){
    return a++;
  }
```

The sample.ll contains :

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define i32 @test(i32) #0 {
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %4 = add nsw i32 %3, 1
  store i32 %4, i32* %2, align 4
  ret i32 %3
}
```

Here, %0 resembles variable a in the source code.

How can I generate a sample.ll like this?

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind
define i32 @test(i32 %a) #0 {
entry:
  %a.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %a, i32* %a.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %a.addr, align 4
  %inc = add nsw i32 %0, 1
  store i32 %inc, i32* %a.addr, align 4
  ret i32 %0
}
```

Where %a resembles variable a in the source code.
NB: The clang version I am using is 6.0.0-1ubuntu2~16.04.1

I am using the command : `clang -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -O0 -emit-llvm -c sample.c -o sample.bc` and then `llvm-dis sample.bc`

Comment: How are you running clang?  When I do `clang -cc1 test.c -S -emit-llvm`, I see the second version

Comment: I am using `clang -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -O0 -emit-llvm -c sample.c -o sample.bc` and then `llvm-dis sample.bc`

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save the variable name when use clang to generate llvm ir？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432967/how-to-save-the-variable-name-when-use-clang-to-generate-llvm-ir)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to name isn't an Instruction, it's an Argument. The [Argument constructor](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Argument.html#a5f424034cc075c4509906e4108374647) takes a Name argument, which is probably the intended way to set that. I've no idea why clang doesn't do that in your case. You can also call [setName()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a35ee267850af7c235474a8c46c7ac5af) later.

Making instructions have names follows the same pattern, provided that they don't have a void type. In your example, `alloca` and `inc` both have names. Making the `load` have a name would usually be done by [passing a NameStr argument](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoadInst.html). [setName()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a35ee267850af7c235474a8c46c7ac5af) works on Instructions too (both Instruction and Argument inherit Value).